# Import list of contact groups in GAS

Tags: google-contacts-api

I can't find anything related in Stack Overflow on this.

I'm trying to post a list of my google contact group names and id's into F16:G.

The code I'm using keeps saying: "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 39, file "email")"

Please help! I'm not good at arrays! An explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be awesome as well!

```
function importContactGroups() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Load Email");
   var dataRow = dataSheet.getRange("F16:F");

   var groupArray = new Array();



//var groups = Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of your Gmail Contacts group here:");

 //var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 



  //var myContacts = ContactsApp.findContactGroup(groupName).getContacts();


  var groups  = ContactsApp.getContactGroups();
 for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {

   var groupNames = groupArray.push(groups[i].getName());

 };

dataSheet.getRange(16, 4, groupArray.length, 5).setValues(groupArray);


 // for (i=0; i < myContacts.length; i++) {
   // var myContact = [[myContacts[i].getFullName(), myContacts[i].getPrimaryEmail(), "Pending"]];
    //mySheet.getRange(i+2, 1,1,3).setValues(myContact);
  //}
  //Browser.msgBox("You have successfully imported " + myContacts.length + " contacts from Gmail. Please proceed to Step 3.");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code on my end and this is the line that causes the error.

```
dataSheet.getRange(16, 4, groupArray.length, 5).setValues(groupArray);
```

First, you dont have to use  this kind of array in JS:

```
var groupArray = new Array();
```

This type of array will work fine

```
 var groupArray = ["a","b","c"];
```

Now to address your issue with `.setValues`, follow the [given format from the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues):

```
// The size of the two-dimensional array must match the size of the range.
 var values = [
   [ "2.000", "1,000,000", "$2.99" ]
 ];
```

So to fix your code you need to have a 2D array format for "groupArray". Here's a working concept demo of your code, hope you be able to apply it on your situation:

```
function importContactGroups() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var dataRow = dataSheet.getRange("F16:F");

   var groupArray = [
       [ "apple", "banana", "orange" ,"jackfruit","kiwi" ]
   ];

  dataSheet.getRange(1, 4, groupArray.length, 5).setValues(groupArray);
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you noogui. I found out that setValues() and setValue() are a big difference. These two can be used with a range. One is plural, the other singular. appendRow() must be used at the sheet level.